# Program never reaches a certain point

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, multidimensional-array, serversocket

**UPDATE:**
Turns out that I was initializing my inputstream on both my Server and Client at the same time and that was what was causing the problem.

In the server side of an application I am making: I never reach one part of the code, which causes my client end to block at that point. Initially I assumed there weren't enough resources for it to run the program, so I quit all my other applications and tried again. I left it running for an hour, still to no avail.

How can I figure out what's wrong? I can't understand where it might be blocking and it can't be stuck in an infinite loop anywhere before that point.

```
 String[][] coordinates1 = new String[10][10], coordinates2 = new String[10][10];
 public void run() {
    //initializes the 10x10 grids for the player
    synchronized (this) {
        //outer loop is for the rows
        for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
            //the inner loop is for the columns
            for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < 10; loop2++) {
                coordinates1[loop][loop2] = "~ ";
                coordinates2[loop][loop2] = "~ ";
            }
        }
    }
    if (player == 1) {
        //deals with the client assuming it is player1
        //declares Object i/o streams
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            //initializes i/o streams
            in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            //writes the two 10x10 grids to the client
            out.writeObject(coordinates2);
            out.writeObject(coordinates1);
            out.flush();
            ...
            }
```

The part it never reaches are the "out.writeObject(..);" lines.

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/fazerlicourice7/Battleships/blob/master/BattleshipServer/src/battleshipserver/Battleship_server_clientThread.java), along with the client end.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: No, I haven't tried using a debugger. Any recomendations?

Comment: Did you make sure that there is one instance where player==1?

Comment: @Fazer Then you should really, *really* try it. Makes finding bugs a lot easier (hence the name). Any IDE more sophisticated than notepad/vi will have one.

Comment: Ok, The netbeans debugger is running now. Will let you know what it comes up with. @innoSPG yup, there is definetely an instance where player == 1.

Comment: 'No, I haven't tried using a debugger.' - [sigh]

Comment: I let the netbeans debugger run for hours on end. It didn't come up with anything. There was a progress bar in the top that said x/343mb, which kept increasing initially but then it reset when I wasn't looking at the debugger. This continued for several hours. I eventually just quit it. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not blocked, your program is waiting.**

You never get to the writeObject line, because the preceeding two lines (getInputStream and getOutputStream) will "wait" for the socket to establish a valid connection. You can verify this by placing two log lines around this:

```
in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
```

To fix the problem I would suggest reviewing your code where you are establishing the connection (ServerSockets and Sockets).

Comment: what's stopping the socket from establishing a valid connection immediately?

Comment: ServerSocket not itialized / SS not listening / wrong port / firewall blocks port, could be caused by almost anything. If you want to verify that the receiver end is fine, you can always try it with telnet: "telnet IP PORT".